# How Do I Wrap Text In A Tkinter Python Notebook Tab And Keep The Width Of Tkinter Notebook Tab Constant

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a pretty simple question really. So I am making a To - Do List, and it requires having a Tkinter Notebook element that will have tabs on the side with the title and date of people's notes, and on the right will be the text editor where the user will store their notes.

However, what is happening is that I cannot set a width and height that is the same for each of the tabs. The tabs keep increasing and decreasing in size based on the user's note title, but what I want to happen is either only some of the title to appear and dissappear when the title's text goes over the size of the width of the tabs. Otherwise, what I would like to happen is for the text to wrap and the height to increase (but in no case the width).

In the following code the titles are the `one one one`, `two two two`, and `three three three` text. I have tried to use `.grid_propagate(FALSE)` with no luck.

```
from tkinter import *
import datetime
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
import tkinter as tk
root = Tk()
root.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)


root.title("To - Do List")
root.geometry("1200x600")
root.configure(background = "white")
# Variable list:

style = ttk.Style()
style.configure(root, tabposition = "wn")

TasksList = ttk.Notebook(root)

Task1 = tk.Frame(TasksList, bg='white', width=600, height=500)
TasksList.add(Task1,text = 'One One One One One One')
Task1.grid_propagate(FALSE)

Task2 = tk.Frame(TasksList, bg='white', width=600, height=200)
TasksList.add(Task2, text = 'Two Two Two Two Two Two')
Task2.grid_propagate(FALSE)

Task3 = tk.Frame(TasksList, bg = "white", width = 600, height = 200)
TasksList.add(Task3, text = "Three Three Three Three Three Three Three")
Task3.grid_propagate(FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do anything about the widths of the tabs. Given the design you are trying to achieve, the simplest solution is to not use the notebook widget. Instead, just use a single text widget, with a listbox to display the list of notes.

In the following example, notes are stored in a dictionary (`self.notes`), with the keys being the note titles. For the sake of simplicity this doesn't handle the case of notes with identical titles, and new notes are appended without sorting. It also only saves a note when you switch notes.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Example():
    def __init__(self):
        root = tk.Tk()
        self.lb = tk.Listbox(root, width=10)
        self.text = tk.Text(root)

        self.lb.pack(side="left", fill="y")
        self.text.pack(side="right", fill="both", expand=True)

        self.current = None
        self.notes = {}

        self.lb.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", self.show_item)

    def show_item(self, event=None):
        selection = self.lb.curselection()
        if selection:
            index = selection[0]
            title = self.lb.get(index)

            # save current note
            if self.current:
                self.notes[self.current] = self.text.get("1.0", "end-1c")

            # show new item
            self.current = title
            self.text.delete("1.0", "end")
            self.text.insert("1.0", self.notes[title])


    def add_note(self, title, body):
        self.notes[title] = body
        self.lb.insert("end", title)

example = Example()
example.add_note("note one", "this is the body of note one")
example.add_note("Note with a really long title", 
                 "this is the body of the note with a long title")
example.add_note("x", "this is the body of note x")

tk.mainloop()
```